# Redshift Sqlalchemy transactions and session management

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

Database - Redshift

SQLAlchemy version - 1.4.2

I'm trying to create a re-usable query using the SQLAlchemy ORM. What I do is something like this.

```
def get_page(query, page_size, page_number):
    return query.limit(page_size).offset((page_number - 1) * page_size).all()

def my_query(self):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        query = session.query(my_model).order_by(
            my_model.id
        )
        return query

query = my_query()

while True:
    page_number = 1
    results = get_page(query, 100, page_number)
    if not results:
        break
    for result in results:
        print(result)
        
    page_number+=1
```

I'm experiencing unexpected behavior using this method on very large data sets. Where it will miss a bunch of entries, or will repeat some of the entries it has already done.  (entry A could appear on page 1 and 4 for some reason)

I'm assuming my problem is that every time i get a page and call `.all()` it is performing a brand new query so if new data is put onto the table it will now effect my results.

This is a watered down example of my real world use case.
The real scenarios query is a left join on two tables.
Table X (a join table) and table Y (The data to act on)
I join table Y to table X and find all of Y that does not have a corresponding X entry.

I iterate through my results using the method above and after 500 entries are processed i create 500 join entries on table X that reference the processed table Y entry.(keeping track of what data has been processed this way)

What I want to have happen is have all the results from my query -> Stream them by chunks of 100, process them, and be able to perform bulk inserts onto the join table without effecting my initial query results or committing my query session(resulting in me requerying and ending up with different results). (meaning if the data changes it is not changed in my results of the initial query)

Tell me what is wrong with my method?

Answer (score 0):

For this to be happening these different queries would need to be in different transactions (xid).  Can you confirm this is what is happening?  (I say this b/c if they happen in the same transaction you should get the same version of the tables.  And it sounds like from your description that this isn't just result ordering differences.)

So the first solution would be to have everything happen in a single transaction (if possible).  The best way to run this would be with a cursor to store the results between fetches.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/declare.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/fetch.html

If it isn't possible to be in a single transaction, then can it be in a single session?  This way you could keep the results in a temp table and read from there.

If these queries absolutely need to be made across separate connections then you will need to set up a perm table to hold results.  This has the disadvantage of needing to be cleaned up when the process ends.  You will want to add some per iteration random chars to the table name so that no iteration collisions can happen on the table name.

I'd start by examining the system tables for these queries on Redshift and note the pid and xid of each.  This will give you more specific information on how SQLAlchemy is interacting with Redshift and what changes are needed.